# Is it a good way to use numpy.ndarray.strides attribute like this?

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, attributes, attr

While browsing through attributes, I found that I can change `np.ndarray.strides` attribute explicitly like so:

```
arr = np.array([8, 3, 4], dtype=np.uint16)
arr.strides = 1
arr
>>> array([  8, 768,   3], dtype=uint16)
```

I know intuitively this is not safe way to assign an attribute explicitly (might be antipattern). Despite that, I know very well, what it is supposed to do.

Another way to get my expected result is:

```
np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(arr, shape=(3,), strides=(1,))
```

I'm looking for any guidelines about patterns of programming that helps to understand, should I avoid setting attributes like this.

Also, is there a safer way in `numpy` to assign a new value to `.strides` attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view` is a newer, safer cover for `as_strided`.  However most uses of these use a `strides` that is as big as the original (here 2).  They return a `view`, rather than modify the array itself.

Your array, and 2 ways of viewing the individual bytes:

```
In [529]: arr = np.array([8,3,4],'uint16')
In [530]: arr
Out[530]: array([8, 3, 4], dtype=uint16)
In [531]: arr.tobytes()
Out[531]: b'\x08\x00\x03\x00\x04\x00'
In [532]: arr.view('uint8')
Out[532]: array([8, 0, 3, 0, 4, 0], dtype=uint8)
```

your strides change is just a portion of

```
In [533]: np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(arr, strides=(1,), shape=(6,))
Out[533]: array([   8,  768,    3, 1024,    4,    0], dtype=uint16)

In [535]: _.astype('uint8')
Out[535]: array([8, 0, 3, 0, 4, 0], dtype=uint8)
```

I think the `768` comes from the `0 3`

```
In [537]: np.array([0,3],'uint8').view('uint16')
Out[537]: array([768], dtype=uint16)
```

So even though your `strides` is (1,), it is still `uint16` as the dtype, so displaying `(8,0), (0,3), (3,0), [(0,4), (4,0)]`.  Actually the safe `as_strided` should have used `shape=(5,)`, since the 6 actually "steps off the end".

So while changing `strides` as you do is possible, I don't think it's useful.  I haven't see anyone else use it.  And as I show, interpreting the results requires some in depth knowledge of dtypes (and their relation to shape and strides).

Comment: Thanks for the respose, hpaulj. I know how that swap of byte positions affects results, for sure and, moreover, I'm convinced that changing `.strides` attribute externally is not useful now. So it looks like such kind of attribute change should be avoided in general, isn't it? By, [GeeksForGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/getter-and-setter-in-python/), it's is recommended to use `setter` & `getter` or properties. Not sure if authors of `numpy` is doing that but at least they have implemented a setter method for `flags`: `np.ndarray.setflags(write=True)`